# while running my android project i m getting a null pointer exception error.the detailed description is given below

Tags: android

while running my android project I m getting an error which does not allow me to upload images from the gallery, I hope that this error is causing the problem but I m not sure, please help get rid of this error.

```
setActionBar();
scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
regionSpinnerSetup();
categorySpinnerSetup();
```

Comment: Paste the exception message please.

Comment: @crash 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference'  
this is the error.how to correct it? why its occuring?

Comment: in any method (setActionBar, or regionSpinnerSetup, or categorySpinnerSetup) you are setting an OnClickListener in a button that is not connected to your java class with the FindViewById method.